# Windows Application in Gujarati language

Tags: fonts, desktop-application, windows

I want to develop Widows Application in Gujarati language. But i don't have any idea how to do this?

So Can any one give me suggestion what to do to develop Desktop windows application in Gujarati font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply globalization to your application no matter what language you are chosen to develop this.Refer these links to get an idea how to do this.These are the following examples show how to develop a window application in C#.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/186760/How-to-develop-Software-in-language-Marathi-Hindi

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15248/Globalization-of-Windows-Applications-in-20-Minute

Hope this will help you.